# Assembly Compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, assembly

Does anyone know a development tool and compiler for Assembly/Assembler. I am not planning on delevoping apps in this, merely just to get my feet wet with Assembly and write Hello World apps etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for thumbulator at github.com, it is a thumb (arm reduced instruction set) instruction set simulator.  There are a few examples, not much on teaching but gets you at least some examples on how to assemble and link.   you really only need binutils (./configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=/something : make all install) for assembler for arm and a number of platforms. if you dont want to do that just get the lite version from code sourcery, they build a good gcc based cross compiler/tools for arm.  binutils is part of that package.  I also have an msp430 instruction set simulator, a very good instruction set for learning assembler (x86 is about the worst instruction set for learning assembler, so do that one last), the msp simulator (I may have called it mspulator) is not as well tested as the thumb one, at the same time it is significantly simpler and if you have problems you can likely debug it yourself or shoot me a note and I will fix it.   Bottom line I recommend learning against a simulator where you have good visibility, qemu does not fall into that category for example.  I would avoid x86 assembler until you are well versed in a few other, better, instruction sets.  msp430 is very good as a first instruction set.  arm and thumb (hold off on thumb2 until you do the other two) are pretty good.  Supposedly dlx/mips but I dont have personal experience (see the SPIM answer).  After that then avr or 8051.  The old pic (not dspic or pic32) is educational, but you see its limitations quickly, helps you with wrapping your head around the problem in a different way.

You may find I have some xmos xcore examples at github, I am back and forth on the xcore.  The tools are excellent, simulator, etc.  Documentation is not bad but not great which lead to my samples.  But at the assembler level I would call this advanced, but am still on the fence as to recommending it as a learning tool.  Go with one of the others first and then maybe look at the xcore and these samples.  Maybe someday I will work through some samples that dont get into threading and thread to thread communication, and then maybe recommend it as not advanced.

Comment: We need more folks that understand the low level, hoping that your experience is a relatively good one and you stick with it long enough to see how things work behind the curtain.  good luck

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need a *compiler* for assembler since you intend to execute the code directly on the machine, so you just need an... *assembler*. If you're in Linux, use `as`.

Answer (score 2):

I know about MASM and NASM. If you are into C/++ you could use the inline assembler.
Btw when you are programming assembly you dont have a compiler but an assembler.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SPIM](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpages.cs.wisc.edu%2F~larus%2Fspim.html&ei=kmkITp2EH5SDtgepnMTmDQ&usg=AFQjCNGimmVE1kBARK3WGpCkh2K7wnp7Ug&sig2=VpRBtgJLumKCjIIGHf9lkQ)

It is a  MIPS processor simulator, designed to run assembly language code for this architecture.

It is just a tool which helps you to learn the basics of assembly language programming.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are the Microsoft Assembler MASM, the Turbo Assembler TASM and the Netwide Assembler NASM, and a few more. At [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler) you will find a lot more information to use in your online search.
But answer this: when you want to write in some assembly language, you must also choose a specific platform where your code should work. Do you know your target platform already? Linux? Windows? MS-DOS? OS-X? OS/2? AmigaDOS? Some specific mobile device?
And when you've chosen the platform, do you also know which processor you'll be targetting? Will it be a processor from AMD or Intel? Which version? Which revision?

You might be more interested in writing code in C or C++ since those two languages don't really depend on any platform. It's also more practical knowledge since assemblers are becoming outdated real hard these days.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I might stray away from Assembly, just wasn't sure how hard it would be to try.

Comment: Well, the principles of Assembly is simple. It's determining the target operating system, CPU platform and other hardware requirements that make Assembly a pain in the donkey. Standard C (not C++) would actually be the closest you can get to Assembly without those additional worries, even though C is a bit higher level.